# Date Detection Regex in Python

Tags: python, beginner, regex

I worked on a problem from Automate the Boring Stuff Chapter 7:

> Write a regular expression that can detect dates in the DD/MM/YYYY
> format. Assume that the days range from 01 to 31, the months range
> from 01 to 12, and the years range from 1000 to 2999. Note that if the
> day or month is a single digit, it’ll have a leading zero.
>
> The regular expression doesn’t have to detect correct days for each
> month or for leap years; it will accept nonexistent dates like
> 31/02/2020 or 31/04/2021. Then store these strings into variables
> named month, day, and year, and write additional code that can detect
> if it is a valid date. April, June, September, and November have 30
> days, February has 28 days, and the rest of the months have 31 days.
> February has 29 days in leap years. Leap years are every year evenly
> divisible by 4, except for years evenly divisible by 100, unless the
> year is also evenly divisible by 400. Note how this calculation makes
> it impossible to make a reasonably sized regular expression that can
> detect a valid date.

Here's my code:

```
#Program that detects dates in text and copies and prints them

import pyperclip, re
#DD/MM/YEAR format
dateRegex = re.compile(r'(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d\d\d)')
#text = str(pyperclip.paste())
text = 'Hello. Your birthday is on 29/02/1990. His birthday is on 40/09/1992 and her birthday is on 09/09/2000.'

matches = []
for groups in dateRegex.findall(text):
    day = groups[0]
    month = groups[1]
    year = groups[2]
    
    #convert to int for comparisons
    dayNum = int(day)
    monthNum = int(month)
    yearNum = int(year)
    
    #check if date and month values are valid
    if dayNum <= 31 and monthNum > 0 and monthNum <= 12:
        #months with 30 days
        if month in ('04', '06', '09', '11'):
            if not (dayNum > 0 and dayNum <= 30):
                continue
        #February only
        if month == '02':
            #February doesn't have more than 29 days
            if dayNum > 29:
                continue
            if yearNum % 4 == 0:
                #leap years have 29 days in February
                if yearNum % 100 == 0 and yearNum % 400 != 0:
                    #not a leap year even if divisible by 4
                    if dayNum > 28:
                        continue
            else:
                if dayNum > 28:
                    continue
        #all other months have up to 31 days
        if month not in ('02', '04', '06', '09', '11'):
            if dayNum <= 0 and dayNum > 31:
                continue
    else:
        continue
    date = '/'.join([groups[0],groups[1],groups[2]])
    matches.append(date)

if len(matches) > 0:
    pyperclip.copy('\n'.join(matches))
    print('Copied to clipboard:')
    print('\n'.join(matches))
else:
    print('No dates found.')
```

I've tested it out with various different date strings and it works as far as I can tell. I wanted to know about better ways of doing this though. As a beginner and an amateur, I understand there might be methods of writing the above code that are better and I don't mind being guided in the right direction and learning more about them. What is a better way of doing all of the above without using so many if statements?

Answer (score 4):

You can import and use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) rather than validating date yourself.

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date(2020, 9, 9)
datetime.date(2020, 9, 9)
>>> datetime.date(1990, 2, 29)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

As such we can just change all your checks to a call to `datetime.date` in a `try` `except` block.

```py
for groups in dateRegex.findall(text):
    try:
        datetime.date(int(groups[2]), int(groups[1]), int(groups[0]))
        matches.append('/'.join(groups))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Rather than using `'/'.join(groups)` if we use `finditer` we can just use `groups[0]`.
And we'd need to increment the other indexes by one too.

```py
for groups in dateRegex.finditer(text):
    try:
        datetime.date(int(groups[3]), int(groups[2]), int(groups[1]))
        matches.append(groups[0])
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

We can also change the creation of `datetime.date` to use a comprehension.
We need to use `*` to map all the values of the built list to arguments to the function.

```py
for group in dateRegex.finditer(text):
    try:
        datetime.date(*(int(part) for part in group.groups()[::-1]))
        yield group[0]
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

You should also use an `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard to prevent your code from running on import.
And I'd define more functions.

```py
import pyperclip
import datetime
import re

DATE_MATCHER = re.compile(r'(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d\d\d)')


def find_dates(text):
    for group in DATE_MATCHER.finditer(text):
        try:
            datetime.date(*(int(part) for part in group.groups()[::-1]))
            yield group[0]
        except ValueError:
            pass


def main():
    text = 'Hello. Your birthday is on 29/02/1990. His birthday is on 40/09/1992 and her birthday is on 09/09/2000.'
    dates = list(find_dates(text))
    if not dates:
        print('No dates found.')
    else:
        pyperclip.copy('\n'.join(matches))
        print('Copied to clipboard:')
        print('\n'.join(dates))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: @FMc Sorry, I'm struggling to understand you a little. "if the else-block in main() had a way of running" - the else does run so I'm guessing you meant something else?

Answer (score 3):

Reading into the question somewhat, there is emphasis on not only matching to a date pattern where the digits and separators are in the right places, such as

```
98/76/5432
```

which your pattern would accept; but to narrow this - with the *pattern itself* - knowing what digits are allowable in which positions. One basic improvement is to constrain the range of the leading digits:

```
date_regex = re.compile(
    r'([0-3]\d)'
    r'/([01]\d)'
    r'/([12]\d{3})'
)
```

This is not perfect but certainly gets you to "within the neighbourhood" of a pattern that will skip invalid dates.

As an exercise to you: how do you think you would extend the above to disallow dates like

```
00/09/1980
38/10/2021
```

?

Comment: `(0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/([12]\d{3})` would match the given requirements more precisely.